# Why do Data Explorer and Stack Overflow data dumps have different schemas?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

I have downloaded the Stack Overflow data dump and imported it into a MySQL database. There were six XML files in the dump, so I created six tables, one for each XML file present in the dump:

`badges`, `comments`, `postHistory`, `posts`, `users`, `votes`

But using the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries), I could see the Data Explorer has more tables than the six mentioned above. Also, accordinly to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer), the tables present in Data Explorer are:

`posts`, `users`, `comments`, `badges`, `postFeedback`, `postHistory`, `postHistoryTypes`, `postTags`, `PostTypes`, `SuggestedEdits`, `SuggestedEditVotes`, `Tags`, `TagSynonyms`, `Votes`, `VoteTypes`

I need to calculate some metrics related to suggestion of edits. That's why I need to access tables such as `SuggestedEdits` and `SuggestedEditVotes`. Can someone tell me why the public dump does not have those tables?

I need to perform an offline computation. That's why I need a database locally stored on my computer because I can't access the online Data Explorer.

Comment: My guess is that "No one's had time to update the data dump appropriately" is the reason.

Answer (score 6):

The goal of the data dump is to preserve the content and set it free in case something happens to Stack-Overflow-the-Company.

Dragging a whole bunch of metadata along with it would be handy for the occasional heavy computation, I agree, but it won't be useful to the majority of people. We also depend on external hosting (thanks, archive.org!) for these dumps, so adding any more data than we have to would be suboptimal.

There's some additional data available through [the API](//api.stackexchange.com), though I don't think it includes suggested edit votes at this time.